# optimising the cpp code of radial basis function(for gamut mapping) to reduce the execution time

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have implemented gamut mapping algorithm for an image processing pipeline. But unfortunately its taking way too long for executing. Approximately it takes 32 minutes of execution time for an RGB image of sizes 256x512(main reason is the idx for loop which is computing a radial basis function). I am trying to reduce its execution time but I wasn't able to make any considerable improvements. I am not trying to do any compiler optimizations because I need to feed this logic in Vivado hls to generate hardware. I have attached to code below.

Any pointers on improving the code will be highly appreciated.

```
Mat img_rev = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/output_rev.png");
Mat ideal = imread("C:/Users/20181217/Desktop/images/imgs/output_fwd_v5.png");
//waited radial basis function
Mat rbf_ctl_pts(img_rev.rows, img_rev.cols, CV_32FC3, 0.0);//intializing with zeros's
// convert the default BGR layout into RGB layout
cvtColor(img_rev, img_rev, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
cvtColor(ideal, ideal, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
//converting to float
img_rev.convertTo(img_rev, CV_32F);

//descaling the given image
img_rev = img_rev / 256.0;

//splitting rbf_ctrl_pts
vector<Mat> vec_channels_rbf;
split(rbf_ctl_pts, vec_channels_rbf);
Mat red_rbf = vec_channels_rbf[0].clone();
Mat green_rbf = vec_channels_rbf[1].clone();
//cout << green_rbf;
Mat blue_rbf = vec_channels_rbf[2].clone();
//splitting the given image
vector<Mat> vec_channels;
split(img_rev, vec_channels);
Mat red = vec_channels[0].clone();
Mat green = vec_channels[1].clone();
Mat blue = vec_channels[2].clone();
// defining the Mat's for the subraction of (x-xn)
Mat red_sub(red.rows, red.cols, CV_32FC1);
Mat green_sub(red.rows, red.cols, CV_32FC1);
Mat blue_sub(red.rows, red.cols, CV_32FC1);
Mat red_new(red.rows, red.cols, CV_32FC1);
Mat green_new(red.rows, red.cols, CV_32FC1);
Mat blue_new(red.rows, red.cols, CV_32FC1);
Mat red_rbf_new(red.rows, red.cols, CV_32FC1);
Mat green_rbf_new(red.rows, red.cols, CV_32FC1);
Mat blue_rbf_new(red.rows, red.cols, CV_32FC1);

float dist;
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < img_rev.rows; i++)//rows =256
{
    for (int j = 0; j < img_rev.cols; j++)//cols =512
    {
        for (int idx = 0; idx < num_ctrl_pts; idx++)//num_ctrl_pts =3702 // ctrl_pts size is 3702x3
        {
            red_sub.at<float>(i, j) = red.at<float>(i, j) - ctrl_pts[idx][0];
            
            green_sub.at<float>(i, j) = green.at<float>(i, j) - ctrl_pts[idx][1];
            
            blue_sub.at<float>(i, j) = blue.at<float>(i, j) - ctrl_pts[idx][2];
            
            dist = sqrt((red_sub.at<float>(i, j)*red_sub.at<float>(i, j)) +
                (green_sub.at<float>(i, j)*green_sub.at<float>(i, j)) +
                (blue_sub.at<float>(i, j)*blue_sub.at<float>(i, j)));
            
            //update the RBF points for each pixel based on the euclidian distance and weights.
            red_rbf.at<float>(i, j) = red_rbf.at<float>(i, j) + (weights[idx][0] * dist);
            green_rbf.at<float>(i, j) = green_rbf.at<float>(i, j) + (weights[idx][1] * dist);
            blue_rbf.at<float>(i, j) = blue_rbf.at<float>(i, j) + (weights[idx][2] * dist);
            

        }cout << j;//printing the column number
        
        red_new.at<float>(i, j) = red_rbf.at<float>(i, j) + coefs[0][0] + red.at<float>(i, j)* coefs[1][0] + green.at<float>(i, j) * coefs[2][0] + blue.at<float>(i, j)* coefs[3][0];
        green_new.at<float>(i, j) = green_rbf.at<float>(i, j) + coefs[0][1] + red.at<float>(i, j)* coefs[1][1] + green.at<float>(i, j) * coefs[2][1] + blue.at<float>(i, j)* coefs[3][1];
        blue_new.at<float>(i, j) = blue_rbf.at<float>(i, j) + coefs[0][2] + red.at<float>(i, j)* coefs[1][2] + green.at<float>(i, j) * coefs[2][2] + blue.at<float>(i, j)* coefs[3][2];
        


    }
    cout << endl << i << endl;//printing the row number
}



//Merge R,G and B channels into a single RGB image
vector<Mat> combine;
combine.push_back(red_new);
combine.push_back(green_new);
combine.push_back(blue_new);
Mat final_img;
merge(combine, final_img);

//conversion to RGB image
final_img = final_img *255.0;
//set the bounds for the iamge between 0 and 255
final_img = max(min(final_img, 255), 0);
//type cast to unsigned char type 
final_img.convertTo(final_img, CV_8U);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: When you profiled the code, which sections took up the most execution time?  Don't optimize without profiling.

Comment: If I am right, your basis functions are a linear function of the distance and increase rather than decay. What sense does this make ?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: obviously there is this main loop executed 256 x 512 x 3702 times (about half a billion), performing a Euclidean distance computation and a multiply & add on a color vector.

Comment: `red_sub.at<float>(i, j)` is a really slow way to access pixels. Get a pointer to the image data, and use pointer arithmetic.

Comment: And if you don't need `red_rbf` outside the loop, why store these values?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: unfortunately, these optimizations will improve the performance of the OpenCV implementation, but have no impact on the Vivaldo code, as the computation remains identical.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: But the 32 minutes that OP is complaining about is the OpenCV code, not the hardware implementation, I presume?

Comment: There are 6 intermediate images that do not need to be stored, using a scalar instead of an image for these 6 values will reduce the computation time by a large margin. The computations performed are rather trivial, I cannot imagine this taking half an hour for a 256x512 image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: if you didn't get the whole post: "I am not trying to do any compiler optimizations because I need to feed this logic in Vivado hls to generate hardware."

Comment: @yves: Yes, you already pointed that out earlier. But OP is timing **this** OpenCV code and complaining about its time. OP is not complaining about the time of the hardware implementation because they don’t have one. The time of this code is dominated by terrible practices, and is not indicative of the time it actually takes to do these computations. This is why I mention these things as a comment, not as an answer. There is nothing here to optimize until the computational cost is first analyzed correctly.

Comment: @yves: Also, a hardware implementation will also suffer from storing intermediate values in the otherwise unused intermediate images.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: this is a straight triple loop with about 13 flops. Benchmarking will tell you nothing more.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, 1. I am using "red_rbf" outside the idx loop,
2. Thanks for the scalar suggestion, I will try it out and update you regarding that

Comment: @YvesDaoust, CrisLuengo, You guys are indeed correct, I am no trying to speed up the opencv application, I am trying to speed up the logic. I have seen some examples for which some sort of optimizations has been done to speed up(like inter changeing nested loops). I was hoping for those kind of ideas. I thought speeding  up the logic helps both the opencv and hardware implementation.

Comment: @Anoop: If you use `red_rbf` outside the loops, at least use a local variable to accumulate the value for one pixel in the inner loop, and then write the value only once to the image. This reduces the memory access by a factor of 3702. If the images are stored row-wise, then your loop order is correct -- you're looping over pixels in the order in which they're stored in memory, and you're looping over pixels only once.

Comment: But again, timing of this code has nothing to do with timing of the hardware code, you worry about it taking 30 minutes, but that is unrelated to how long a hardware implementation will take. So either simulate the hardware and ask here how to optimize the hardware implementation, or aks us to optimize this piece of code ignoring the fact that you want to translate to a hardware implementation. The question as it stands cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

This code will parallelize easily as every pixel is handled separately, and for every pixel every control point is handled separately (with a global accumulation, though). So if you have enough FPGA space to replicate the processing, you should get perfect speedup.

Besides this, unless you are ready to accept some approximation, I see no way to reduce the workload.

For example, if your mapping function is smooth, you can precompute a number of spaced points in RGB space, say 16 per component (16 x 16 x 16 x 3072 computations), then map the whole image using trilinear interpolation between the surrounding 8 RGB values for every pixel.

Even better if you need a single map for several images: the precomputed LUT can be reused.

If that makes sense, you could also cluster the close control points and replace the clusters by an average.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Unfortunately, the implementation is not supposed to accept any approximations as the scenario of the image is always changing

Comment: @AnoopKrishna: you get my last word: hopeless then.